# Getting data for a certain row in a table - Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a table with input fields from which I have to get information and save it, but I also have to get information from every certain row in the table. I have one submit button for the whole table.

I need to get the id of the `$student` and the id of the `$subject`. How can i get them?

I'm posting the table

```
 <table class="table table-responsive table-striped" id="admin-table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Клас:</th>
        <th>N:</th>
        <th>Име:</th>
        <th>Предмет:</th>
        <th>Оценка:</th>
        <th>Тип на оценката:</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($students as $student)
        @foreach($class as $classes)
          @foreach($sub as $subject)
        <tr>
            <td>
                {{$classes->name}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{$student->number_in_class}}

            </td>
            <td>
                {{$student->full_name}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{$subject}}
            </td>
            {!! Form::open(['action' => 'Educator\AccountController@markStudent', 'class' => 'form-horizontal']) !!}
            <td>
                {!! Form::text('mark',null, ['class'=>'form-control col-md-2']) !!}
            </td>
            <td>
                {!! Form::select('markType', $markType, null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
            </td>
        </tr>
            @endforeach
          @endforeach
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
    <div align="center">
        <a href="{{url('educator/class-subject')}}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Назад</button></a>
        {!! Form::submit('Запиши', ['class' => 'btn btn-default']) !!}

    </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

The method in the controller:

```
public function postIndex(Request $request)
{

    $user = Auth::user();

    ClassSubject::where([
        ['subject_id', $request->input('subject')],
        ['class_id', $request->input('class')]
    ])->get();

    return view('educator.account.input', [
        'user' => $user,
        'class'=> Clas::where('id', '=', $request->get('class'))
            ->get(),
        'students' => User::where('class_id', '=', $request->get('class'))
            ->orderBy('first_name', 'asc')
            ->get(),
        'markType' => MarkType::get()
            ->pluck('type', 'id'),
        'sub' => Subject::where('id', '=', $request->input('subject'))
            ->get()
            ->pluck('name','id')
    ]);

}
```

And the method in which I'm saving the data i need:

```
public function markStudent(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'mark' => 'numeric|required|min:2|max:6',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect()
            ->back()
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
    }

    StudentMark::create([
        'student_id' => the student id which i have to get from the table in the view,
        'subject_id' => $request->the subject id which i have to get from the table in the view,
        'mark_type_id' => $request->input('markType'),
        'mark' => $request->input('mark')]);

    $user = Auth::user();
    $subject = ClassSubject::where('teacher_id', $user->id)
        ->get()
        ->pluck('subject_id', 'id');


    return view('educator.account.marks', [
        'user' => Auth::user(),
        'marks' => StudentMark::whereIn('subject_id',$subject)
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->get(),
    ]);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `Form::open` up, put it somewher after `@foreach` clauses, but before data:

Then change layout to this:

```
<td>
    {!! Form::label('classes_name', $classes->name) !!}
</td>
<td>
    {!! Form::label('student_number_in_class', $student->number_in_class) !!}
</td>
<td>
    {!! Form::label('student_full_name', $student->full_name) !!}
</td>
<td>
    {!! Form::label('subject', $subject) !!}
</td>
```

Then just access this info as usual:

```
$request->input('student_number_in_class'),
```

I've not tested, but this should work. If `label` will not for you, try to use another form type.

Comment: I've edited my post with the controller in which im actually getting the data I need.

Comment: Maybe now I understood you correctly. Please read updated answer.

Comment: Thats a good idea, but unfortunately not working with label and every other type of form wouldn't look okay.

Comment: Text should work. If it's ugly, you could just add `input type="hidden"`. It will not be displayed, but info will definitely will be in request object.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add this query on the controller method that saves your result.

```
$studentid = Student::where('colname','=',colvalue)->select('id')->first();
$subjectid = Subject::where('colname','=',colvalue)->select('id')->first();
```

Any data you have in the view that you are passing to controller. Use that info to get the id of student and subject. I cant get you the exact solution as I don't know the relation between the tables or the column names for each table in the database.

Comment: `colname` is what exactly? 'anycol' is the id in both subject and student.

Comment: `StudentMark::create([
        'student_id' => the student id,
        'subject_id' => the subject id,
        'mark_type_id' => $request->input('markType'),
        'mark' => $request->input('mark')]);`

Comment: Actually anycol is the column name or the column you wish to compare with the model to get the id of it. So here student model with some column name and column value which was passed as input and then finally we get the id for that student. Similarly for subject. Also my bad colname is the column value.

Comment: Yes, i get that, but the subject id and the student id are not in a input field. I'm just looping them in foreach, for example in one row of my table in the view i have :  `student_id, subject_id, input field for mark, and input field for marktype`

i need to get not only the input fields but the subject_id and student_id exactly in this row.

Comment: Oh i get it. Do you mean you have some raw values that are not inputs but still needs to be passed onto the controller?

Comment: Normally its the job of controller to pass data to views. And by only means you can pass data fro. View to co troller is using form. What you can do is add them in html input elements like those two you did and set input field to disabled. So users can see those info but cant change it and also you can simply thn pass it to the controller and store thm too. Or you can simply hide the input field as hidden and pass studentid which you can use it to findorfail query and retrieve all relevant data. Hope this helps. Let me know if you want me to show any of my methods.

Comment: Yeah, that was the thing I just tried and it worked, thanks. :)